# jsoup java html parsing

Tags: java, html, apache-poi, jsoup

I'm a new french user on stack and I have a problem ^^

I use an HTML parse Jsoup for parsing a html page. For that it's ok but I can't parse more url in same time.

This is my code:

first class for parsing a web page

```
package test2;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public final class Utils {

    public static Map<String, String> parse(String url){

        Map<String, String> out = new HashMap<String, String>();

        try
        {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

            doc.select("img").remove();

            Elements denomination = doc.select(".AmmDenomination");
            Elements composition = doc.select(".AmmComposition");
            Elements corptexte = doc.select(".AmmCorpTexte");


            for(int i = 0; i < denomination.size(); i++)
            {
                out.put("denomination" + i, denomination.get(i).text());
            }

            for(int i = 0; i < composition.size(); i++)
            {
                out.put("composition" + i, composition.get(i).text());
            }

            for(int i = 0; i < corptexte.size(); i++)
            {
                out.put("corptexte" + i, corptexte.get(i).text());
                System.out.println(corptexte.get(i));
            }

        } catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return out;
    }//Fin Methode parse


    public static void excelizer(int fileId, Map<String, String> values){

        try
        {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("C:/Documents and Settings/c.bon/git/clinsearch/drugs/src/main/resources/META-INF/test/fichier2.xls" );
            Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
            Sheet mySheet = wb.createSheet();
            Row row1 = mySheet.createRow(0);
            Row row2 = mySheet.createRow(1);

            String entete[] = {"CIS", "Denomination", "Composition", "Form pharma", "Indication therapeutiques", "Posologie", "Contre indication", "Mise en garde",
                    "Interraction", "Effet indesirable", "Surdosage", "Pharmacodinamie", "Liste excipients", "Incompatibilité", "Duree conservation",   
                    "Conservation", "Emballage", "Utilisation Manipulation", "TitulaireAMM"};

            for (int i = 0; i < entete.length; i++)
            {
                row1.createCell(i).setCellValue(entete[i]);
            }


            Set<String> set = values.keySet();
            int rowIndexDenom = 1;
            int rowIndexCompo = 1;

            for(String key : set)
            {
                if(key.contains("denomination"))
                {
                    mySheet.createRow(1).createCell(1).setCellValue(values.get(key));
                    rowIndexDenom++;
                }
                else if(key.contains("composition"))
                {
                    row2.createCell(2).setCellValue(values.get(key));
                    rowIndexDenom++;
                }
            }
            wb.write(out);
            out.close();
        }   
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

second class

```
package test2;

public final class Task extends Thread {

    private static int fileId = 0;
    private int id;
    private String url;


    public Task(String url)
    {
        this.url = url;
        id = fileId;
        fileId++;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        Utils.excelizer(id, Utils.parse(url));
    }
}
```

the main class (entry point)

```
package test2;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ArrayList<String> urls = new ArrayList<String>();
        urls.add("http://base-donnees-publique.medicaments.gouv.fr/affichageDoc.php?specid=61266250&typedoc=R");
        urls.add("http://base-donnees-publique.medicaments.gouv.fr/affichageDoc.php?specid=66207341&typedoc=R");

        for(String url : urls)
        {
            new Task(url).run();
        }

    }

}
```

When the data was copied to my excel file, the second url doesn't work.

Can you help me solve my problem please?

Thanks

Comment: Are the two whitespaces a normal thing in your first link in main class ?

Comment: "base-donnees-  publique.medicaments.gouv.fr" yes why the space in url?

Comment: it's just an error when i do the copy paste sorry, but i need to parse 13 000 url :/ : And i have an other probleme i take the information with the .class attribut but in the document for not same data we have a same .class, for all attribut  it's .AmmCorpsTexte the probleme was when i want to collect all date he take only the last : i'm hope you understand beacause my english it's very bad :/

Comment: Is there any reason you **1)** don't run those threads concurrently (your question suggests you are trying to run the threads in parallel) **2)** overwrite the file?     Also please add more detail what exactly you are trying to do and what your program does instead.

Comment: For work i need to get information of web page, you go to this link http://base-donnees-publique.medicaments.gouv.fr/index.php, you select an letters after you select a drugs and you arrived on page with 3 tab and i need to take the information of the second tab and copy all data in a xls file, but i need to do that for all drugs :  the probleme is : how to do that on all page (i have 13 000 pages ? And the second pb is when i want to take the information with the class attr in html document i have the same atribu but when i take this atribut jsoup take only the last the atr is .AmmCorpsTexte

Answer (score 1):

I think its because your `main()` exits before your second thread has a chance to do its job. You should wait for all spawned threads to complete using `Thread.join()`. Or better yet, create one of the `ExecutorService`'s and use `awaitTermination(...)` to block until all URLs are parsed.
**EDIT** See some examples here http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/01/java-thread-pool-example-using-executors-and-threadpoolexecutor.html

Comment: Certainly not. The threads don't even run concurrently. (`run()` instead of `start()`). And let's add: Even if they were executed concurrently, the jvm would not exit as long as there are non-daemon-threads running. But running them concurrently would be unhealthy, since they write to the same file.

Comment: do you have an example i don't now you things :/ please